# can we use <span> to hold image file?

Tags: html

What is the purpose of the empty `<span>` in the below code. I always thought `<span>` was used to style inline elements. However, in the below code it looks like `<span>` is used to hold the image file? 
can someone please explain the purpose of the `<span>` tag here?

thanks in advance! :)

```
<ul>
<li><a href="index.php?id=1" class="selected">Home</a></li>
<span><img src="assets/images/divider.png" /></span>
</ul>
```

Comment: It's invalid HTML too...

Comment: The title of the question asks a question entirely different from the question in the body, which is speculative and cannot be answered without information about styles and scripts used.

Answer (score 1):

It serves no purpose whatsoever as far as rendering the HTML goes. It might be used to match some (poorly written) CSS rule e.g. `ul span` or perhaps as a hook for JavaScript.

It is also invalid as HTML since the only tags permitted within a `<ul>` are `<li>`.

Answer (score 1):

As the others have mentioned having a `span` as a direct descendent of a `ul` is invalid markup.

However perhaps the original author put it there because they wanted an inline element to display an image on the same line?

The same effect could have been acheived with:

```
<li style="display:inline"><img src="assets/images/divider.png" /></li>
```

Although I'll admit that it's a bit of a stretch.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm concerned you may not wrap a block-element inside an inline-element. Even though `img` is `inline-block`, I assume the rule still applies.

Answer (score 0):

In images you don't need to use  to hold and customize the image.

Is always better use id or class in the image tag, for example: